# Is IL instruction "cpobj" applicable for reference types?

Tags: c#, clr, cil

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.cpobj?view=netframework-4.8) says:

> The behavior of cpobj is unspecified if ……, or if classTok does not represent a value type.

But [ECMA 335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf#page=425) says:

> If typeTok is a reference type, the cpobj instruction has the same effect as ldind.ref followed by stind.ref.

Which is correct?

Comment: Make sure you have the latest revision of ecma-335 (currently 6th edition), it also documents the unspecified behavior clause.

Comment: @HansPassant The one OP linked is the one [from here](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/). Where did you find a newer one?

Comment: @HansPassant Please follow the link. It is the 6th and is just from the big "download" on the ECMA website moments ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look through the previous editions of ECMA-335, we find that the 3rd edition changed the wording to specify:

> If typeTok is a reference type, the cpobj instruction has the same effect as ldind.ref followed by stind.ref.

In editions 1 and 2, the wording matched that on MSDN.

Therefore, I think it's safe to conclude that ECMA-335 6th edition is correct, and MSDN is out of date.

Comment: Dated for 20 years, haha.

Comment: Well that depends on what "unspecified" should interpreted as. One could argue that MSDN leaves it unspecified, only for ECMA to specify it later. Both are correct in a way.